# How to integrate Twitter api with mule

Tags: twitter, mule

I want to know how to use twitter api using mule soft

I am working to get data from Twitter using their APIs

In mule 3 we have connector but in mule 4 we didn't have..

Twitter api has..

API key
Api secret key
access token and access token secret

Where i have to use these keys in mulesoft to get data from Twitter..

TIA
SRI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options here. The first is getting a proper API spec, OAS or RAML, that you can publish in your organization's Exchange since that will generate a Twitter connector for you automatically. The second is just using the HTTP connector, but this won't get you any metadata or contextual help, it will be like using any other raw HTTP client.

In any case, you need to carefully review the auth scheme of the API to check exactly how you are suppose to use it. This is not specific to MuleSoft but any REST API. I would try getting a request to work using curl, Postman or whatever HTTP client you like most and then move on to an actual Mule app, it should be straightforward from there. 
HTH

Comment: Thanks so much @afelisatti.

Comment: i am able to genarate the flows using raml, but having a difficulty to authenticate with twitter, can you kindly help how we can do. @afelisatti

Comment: You should not be generating any flows with the Twitter RAML, that's to implement an API not consume one. You need to try and connect to Twitter with Postman, only then would you be able to connect through other clients like Mule. I cannot help you review the auth unless you have a specific issue on the Mule side.